# Azure App Service ModueNotFoundError opencensus

Tags: flask, azure-web-app-service, modulenotfounderror, opencensus

I am trying to use application insights inside of a flask app using:

```
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler
```

but the runtime throws the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opencensus'`

However it works perfectly fine locally. I don't have anything to investigate next What should I do now?

Comment: Open webssh, use `pip install opencensus`, then check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Jason shared, please review, https://pypi.org/project/opencensus/ for further troubleshooting of the module including how to export traces.